# Laravel имена таблиц заглавными буквами

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Знаю, что имена таблиц в Laravel должны именоваться строчными буквами, но в проекте БД в которой имена заданы заглавными и после того как делаю выборку вместо названия отношения **USER** laravel отдает **u_s_e_r**. Вот собственно вопрос - *можно ли реализовать чтобы возвращались данные с именами как в БД*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилось добавлением в модель свойства `public static $snakeAttributes = false;`